# how to store a scanned image into my hard disk or tomcat server using java

Tags: jquery, spring

To acquire the image from scanner device, I have implemented this below jsp.

Now can anybody plz tell me how to store that acquire image into my hard disk or tomcat server using java?

I am using spring in my application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <tittle><h1> Scanning</h1></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://direct.asprise.com/scan/javascript/base/scanner.js"></script> <!-- required for scanning -->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <!-- optional -->

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- optional -->
    <style type="text/css">
        img.zoom { margin-right: 4px; }
        title{
        margin-left: 4px;
        font-family: 
        }
        body { margin: 20px 10px; }
    </style>

    <script>
        // -------------- Optional status display, depending on JQuery --------------
        function displayStatus(loading, mesg, clear) {
            $('#info').empty(); // jQuery is used
            if(loading) {
                $('#info').html((clear ? '' : $('#info').html()) + '<p><img src="http://asprise.com/legacy/product/_jia/applet/loading.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;" hspace="8"> ' + mesg + '</p>');
            } else {
                $('#info').html((clear ? '' : $('#info').html()) + mesg);
            }
        } 
        // -------------- scanning related code: independent of any 3rd JavaScript library --------------

        function scanThenUpload() {
            displayStatus(true, 'Scanning', true);
            com_asprise_scan_request(myCallBackFunc,
                com_asprise_scan_cmd_method_SCAN_THEN_UPLOAD, // scan and then upload directly in the applet UI
                com_asprise_scan_cmd_return_IMAGES_AND_THUMBNAILS,
                {
                    //what i have to do coding here..
                });
        }
        /** Use this callback function to get notified about the scan result. */
        function myCallBackFunc(success, mesg, thumbs, images) {
            var logText;
            displayStatus(false, '', true);
            logText = 'Callback function invoked: success = ' + success + ", mesg = " + mesg;
            logText += '\nThumbs: ' + (thumbs instanceof Array ? thumbs.length : 0) + ", images: " + (images instanceof Array ? images.length : 0);
            logToConsole(logText, !(success || mesg == 'User cancelled.'));
            displayStatus(false, '<pre>' + logText + '</pre>', true);
            for(var i = 0; (images instanceof Array) && i < images.length; i++) {
                addImage(images[i], document.getElementById('images'));
            }
        }
        /** We use this to track all the images scanned so far. */
        var imagesScanned = [];
        function addImage(imgObj, domParent) {
            imagesScanned.push(imgObj);
            var imgSrc = imgObj.datatype == com_asprise_scan_datatype_BASE64 ?
                    'data:' + imgObj.mimetype + ';base64,' + imgObj.data : imgObj.data;
            var elementImg = createDomElementFromModel(
                {
                    'name': 'img',
                    'attributes': {
                        'class': 'scanned',
                        'src': imgSrc,
                        'height': '100',
                        'class': 'zoom'
                    }
                }
            );
            domParent.appendChild(elementImg);
            // optional UI effect that allows the user to click the image to zoom.
            enableZoom();
        }
        function submitForm1() {
            displayStatus(true, "Submitting in progress, please standby ...", true);
            com_asprise_scan_submit_form_with_images('form1', imagesScanned, function(xhr) {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4) { // 4: request finished and response is ready
                    displayStatus(false, "<h2>Response from the server: </h2>" + xhr.responseText, true);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

 <body style="margin: 10px 30px;">
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; right: 30px; top: 20px;">

</div> 



<p style="color: #9eadc0;">
|
</p>

<div class="panel panel-info" style="margin: 20px 0px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Scann your documents here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="form1" action="http://asprise.com/scan/applet/upload.php?action=dump" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank" >
            <label for="field1" style="display: inline-block; width: 150px; text-align: right;">Field 1</label>
            <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" value="value 1"/>
            <br><span style="height: 4px;"></span><br>

            <label style="display: inline-block; width: 150px; text-align: right;">Documents</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="scanSimple();">Simple Scan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="scan();">Scan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="scanThenUpload();">Scan Then Upload</button>

            <div id="images" style="margin-left: 154px; margin-top: 10px;">
            </div>

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit form" onclick="submitForm1();" style="margin-left: 154px; margin-top: 20px;">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- <div id="info" class="well" style="dis`enter code here`play: block; background-color: #fff; height: 500px; margin-top: 12px; padding: 12px; overflow: scroll;">
    <p><i>Information window</i></p>
</div> -->

<!-- <span style="font-family: Arial; color: #999; font-size: 12px;">ALL RIGHTS RESERVED BY LAB ASPRISE <a href="http://asprise.com/" target=_blank>asprise.com</a> &copy; 1998 - 2014.</span> -->

<script src="http://yyx990803.github.io/zoomerang/zoomerang.js"></script>
<script>
    function enableZoom() {
        Zoomerang.config({
            maxWidth: window.innerWidth, // 400,
            maxHeight: window.innerHeight, // 400,
            bgColor: '#000',
            bgOpacity: .85
        }).listen('.zoom');
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, it is not clear that where image exist. Means if you want to upload scan image then it simply file upload scenario.
Another thing if image directly come from scanner to your app then you have to handle it.
e.g; when image scanned you have to download it in process folder and after download you can perform action on that.